# Dynamic Content without reloading page

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, dynamic

I have been racking my brain all night trying to figure this out, and was wondering if I could get some help.

My goal is to build an easy to use admin panel for my website. I want to set up the admin site so that when I click the menu items, the content changes, but the url stays at "http://www.mysite.com/admin/".

Through extensive googling, I have seen people claiming this could be accomplished with JQuery, AJAX, and JSON, but, While I am proficient in HTML, and PHP, I lack the knowledge to script anything in JQuery, AJAX, or JSON.

Is there a way to do this in PHP? If not, How would I go about this? I am not begging for free coding, but fragments would be aperciated just as much as links to places where perhaps I could learn enough to figure it out myself.

-Steven

Comment: [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 1):

I recommended to follow ajax method.

Try using i frames..

your iframe should have a name

```
     <iframe name=blah>
     </iframe>
```

your link should target that name

```
      <a href="http://www.mysite.com/admin/adminpage.php" target="blah">
```

This prevent url to remain the same

Comment: Thank you, that should be exactly what I need....I don't know why I didn't think of using a borderless Iframe, then again, I have been sllep deprived for the past 72 hours. Thank you, JITHIN JOSE!

Comment: please please please don't use iframes. 1) not need, jquery is easy to learn and an ajax response will be better for you in the long run. 2) iframes are generally frowned upon with current web standards.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do asyncrounous client-side-to-server-side requests with a server side PHP code. You will have to use Javascript to initiate AJAX requests.

That said, there might be some PHP framework that generates the Javascript you need, but I don't know of any.

You really should learn Javascript, though, or at least a language that compiles to it. You will be very limited in rich client side interaction if you never use a client-side scripting language.